# Asp.Net MVC How to log all actions being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, action

I need to be able to log all actions that are called from my asp.net mvc application. How and what would be the best way to achieve this? Where I log it to whether it be the console or log file doesn't matter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could create your own class which inherits from [ActionFilterAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and then override the [OnActionExecuting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting%28System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext%29) method.

**Example**

```
public class LogActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var controller = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
        var action = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];

        //
        // Perform logging here
        //

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [LogAction]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice THOROUGH answer ;)

Comment: To anyone wanting to be extremely loggy (like myself), you can add the [LogAction] attribute to above the entire class like so 
[LogAction}
public class HomeController : Controller{}
rather than individual controller.

Answer (score 7):

Credit HeyMega for their answer. Here's an example of an expanded implementation I arrived at in MVC5.

```
public class LogActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var controller = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("Controller") ? filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() : null;
        var action = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("Action") ? filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() : null;
        var area = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("Area") ? filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Area"].ToString() : null;
        var user = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();

        Task.Run(() => Generic().AreaActionLog(user, area, controller, action));

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I chose to separate the method doing the actual logging into a separate process, if anything goes wrong with the Database interaction, or the DB interaction takes several seconds, the UI is uninterrupted.

You can then decorate the entire controller with `[LogAction]` attribute like so.

```
[LogAction]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Or selectively apply the attribute by decorating individual methods:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [LogAction]
    public ActionResult Index_Logs_Things()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) library with its [Audit.MVC](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.Mvc/README.md) and the different data providers to store the logs on files, eventlog, sql, redis, mongo, and much more.

With the [MVC](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.Mvc/README.md) extension you just need to decorate your controllers or actions with an attribute:

```
[Audit]
public class HomeController : Controller
{ ... }
```

Execute a static configuration to set the output of your logs:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseFileLogProvider(_ => _
        .Directory(@"C:\Logs"));
```

And it will provide the infrastructure to log the interactions with your MVC application.